# Subscribe to all web requests in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

Is it possible to subscribe to all web requests in windows phone application?
I mean to register a global hook, that will fire every time i make a request to web server. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example:

```
// Since the property is static, it will be shared by all instances of WebClientWrapper
// Set this before creating an instance of WebClientWrapper
WebClientWrapper.Hook = address => Debug.WriteLine(address);

var webClientWrapper = new WebClientWrapper();
webClientWrapper.DownloadString("http://www.something.com");



public class WebClientWrapper
{
    private readonly WebClient _webClient;

    // This can be string, your custom class of whatever you need
    public static Action<string> Hook { get; set; }

    public WebClientWrapper()
    {
        _webClient = new WebClient();
    }

    public string DownloadString(string address)
    {
        Hook(address);
        return _webClient.DownloadString(address);
    }
}
```